# Linq + Invalid expression term '>'

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can anyone help me here, the following works fine on my xp but not my vista machine.  Im querying a Generic dictionary.

Both computers have .NET 3.5 + SP1, 3.0, 2.0, etc., and have the web project targeted to 3.5 Framework.

```
using System.Linq;
string val = "Test";
var d = DictionaryOfStuff().Where(n => n.Key.ToLower().Contains(val.ToLower()));
```

Gives me the error:
CS1525: Invalid expression term '>'

I can run this in a differnet project on vista, I have IIS configured to use .NET 2.0 and the project in VS targeted at 3.5
I have even tried adding this to the web.config, it compiles fine w/o any lambda/linq

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, here was the answer..

I changed the project to target .NET 3.0, tried to compile got all kinds of errors, changed it back to 3.5 and it compiled fine.

I musta had an old reference in there from something.

Comment: So odd. Same thing happened to me, and the target switch worked fine. Heh, thanks.

Comment: This was a life saver. Thanks for coming back and letting us know what worked! Microsoft...grrrr...

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Target was set to 4.0 and I got the error. Changed to 2.0 and then back to 4.0 and all is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the error message, I would have to say there is a configuration issue on your Vista machine and the web projects are using the 2.0 compiler instead of the 3.5 compiler.  This is the only reason I can think of that you would get this message.

Make sure that

- IIS is configured properly
- Web settings are configured properly.

Comment: I have configured all i can think to, what else might i have to do other than whats mentioned (modified) above?

Answer (score 0):

What is "`val`" in this case?  You never declared it in your sample.  Did you mean "`n.Value`"?

Comment: I edited the above, val is a string passed through a parm, but above should make more sense now :-)

Answer (score 0):

schmoopy you rock :) and Visual studio :P just stuck in same issue since morning :P

http://www.hyperlinksolutions.net
http://barchitect.blogspot.com